# xrandr — Treat multiple monitors as separate screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, external-display, laptop-display, xrandr

I have two monitors:

- Laptop monitor 1920x1080
- External monitor 2560x1440 connected with Display Port cable

Output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+0+360 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.00  
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440    164.80*+ 120.00    99.95    84.98    60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1440x480      59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As you can see, `xrandr` joins the two monitors into one single `Screen 0` (4480x1440). I want to have **two separate screens**: `Screen 0` and `Screen 1` with the laptop monitor being the first one and the external monitor, the second one. I also want to preserve the ability to drag windows from monitor to monitor.

The *wrong* 4480x1440 resolutions messes up with Lutris, and the games are only able to see the 4480x1440 but cannot see 2560x1440.